# How to save an array of objectID in mongoose and add fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to save in an Array the following...

I send this by POST

req.body.products =

```
{id: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", buy: 30, cant:20},
{id: "5936460d2fabd233f2ddace6", buy: 25, cant:14}
```

That id is the ObjectId of an existing product

This is my controller

```
let facturaProv = new provBill({
  id_store: res.locals.store.id,
  name: req.body.name,
  category: req.body.category,
  products: req.body.products
});

facturaProv.save(function(err) {
  if (!err) res.send('OK')
  else res.send("error")
}
});
```

This is my Schema

```
provSchema: new Schema({
  id_store: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'store' },
  category:String,
  name: String,
  products: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product' }]
})
```

How should I modify my schema to save the "buy" and "cant" fields?

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
products: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product', buy: Number, cant:Number }]
```

Thank you for reading and for helping me.

Comment: This is referenced. You need to save the related model first. `mongoose.model("product").create(req.body.products,function(err, products) {` and then in that callback you can create and save your model with the reference.

Answer (score 4):

Modify the schema as following:

```
products: [
  { 
     id : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'product'}, 
     buy: Number,
     cant: Number
  }
]
```

Comment: I have this err 

`{ ValidationError: prov validation failed: productos: Cast to Array failed for value "{id: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", buy: 3, cant:2}" at path "products" `

I sent this : {id: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", buy: 3, cant:2}

Comment: The object you send must have the same properties' names as the object defined in the schema.

Comment: Yes, the real code is using spanish words, my bad. Still not working with same properties

Comment: Another question: did you define the "product" model used for ref. ?!
if you used the ref. by mistake you can try the following:
products: [
  { 
     id : String, 
     buy: Number,
     cant: Number
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct JSON object
`{id: "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", buy: 30, cant:20},
{id: "5936460d2fabd233f2ddace6", buy: 25, cant:14}`

Note the **""**

`{"id": "5936460d2fabd233f0ddaca3", "buy": 30, "cant":20},
{"id": "5936460d2fabd233f2ddace6", "buy": 25, "cant":14}`